# What does a large character offset on line 1 mean in a node backtrace for a non-minified Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting lines in node backtraces like this:

```
at Foo.create (src/api/foo.js:1:9027)
```

The file in question, `foo.js`, is a plain, non-minified JavaScript file. It is not even 9027 characters (or bytes) long in total, never mind line 1.

I searched for what this might mean, but all the answers I found referred either to minified or transpiled code, and this is neither.

The function `Foo.create` is an `async` method of a class in the file.

My question is, what information is "1:9027" encoding?

Comment: It means line 1 column 9027. There is something done to the files you don't know about. They are uglified or minified and probably bundled. That causes files with only one single but very long line. It's even possible that this happens just in time (JIT)

Comment: Is the file being compiled or "transpiled" at all?

Comment: @ThomasSablik, you're exactly right, and I eventually found the culprit: in my case it was nyc/istanbul. Thanks for making me look harder; very happy to accept your answer if you write it up!